# Create and fill a DataFrame column based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame and I need to create a new column and fill the values acording to how many words in a list of words are found in a text. I'm trying de code below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 
               'text': ['water, rainbow', 'blue, red, white','country,school,magic']})


list_of_words = ['water', 'pasta', 'black', 'magic', 'glasses', 'school' ,'book']

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    text = row['text']
        count_found_words = 0
        for word in list_of_words:
            found_words= re.findall(word, text)
            if len(found_words)>0:
                count_found_words += 1
        df['found_words'] = count_found_words
```

This code actually create a new column, but fill all the rows with the last 'count_found_words' of the loop.

is there a right way to do this?

Comment: Does your solution work? What needs to be improved to make it *better*?

Comment: doesnt work, it fills all the columns with the same value, witch comes from the last loop

Comment: Your [mre] should always include a **minimal** example of the data. The *data* can be made up as long as it illustrates the issue.  [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Change `df['found_words'] = count_found_words` to `df.loc[index,'found_words'] = count_found_words`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pattern = fr"\b({'|'.join(list_of_words)})\b"

df["found_words"] = df.text.str.findall(pattern).str.len()
```

This forms the regex `\b(water|pasta|black|magic|glasses|school|book)\b` that looks for any of the words in the list. Finds all it could and reports the number of matches via `.len`.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can TRY:

```
df['found_words'] = df.text.str.split(',').apply(
    lambda x: sum(i in list_of_words for i in x))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define a function count_words that returns count_found_words and use `df['found_words'] = df['text'].map(count_words)`